# Shopify: how to access a Shopify metafield using JavaScript in a .liquid file?

Tags: javascript, shopify, liquid, metaobject

I am trying to access a Shopify metafield using JavaScript in a .liquid file. The metafield is a single line text field.

```
{% javascript %}

  console.log({{product.metafields.custom.sample_name.value}});

{% endjavascript %}
```

Some things I've tried from suggestions elsewhere that did not work...

Suggestion 1: put quotes around the metafield

```
{% javascript %}

  console.log('{{product.metafields.custom.sample_name.value}}');

{% endjavascript %}
```

Suggestion 2: assign the metafield to a variable... but this seems to still be the same as just directly using the metafield

```
{% assign tempVar = product.metafields.custom.sample_name.value %}
{% javascript %}

  console.log(tempVar);

{% endjavascript %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original issue is liquid cannot be rendered within liquid JavaScript tags (?) i.e.:

```
{% javascript %}{% endjavascript %}
```

but I found liquid can still be rendered within script tags outside of liquid js tags...

```
<script></script>
```

So something like this will work...

```
<script>
console.log({{product.metafields.custom.sample_name.value }});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use this:

```
<script>
    console.log({{product.metafields.custom.sample_name.value | json }});
</script>
```

More info about the json filter in liquid:
https://shopify.dev/docs/api/liquid/filters/json

Comment: Thanks so much for the suggestion. This is the code Shopify liquid generates. 

`(function() {
  if (!__sections__["wavesurfer"] && !window.DesignMode) return;
  try {
    
  console.log({{product.metafields.custom.sample_name.value | json }});

  } catch(e) { console.error(e); }
})();`

With the error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{' (at scripts.js?610:143:16)

The issue seems to be that the liquid variable and filter is not accessible with in the JS. Is there a way it can be saved as a json object which is then later accessible to the JS when passed to the browser?

Comment: This should work without problem (use it daily).
Did you try to write simply a <script> tag instead of {% script %}?

Comment: Thanks for the time for your reply. Yes your solution using the <script> tag works. Thanks again.

Comment: I edit the answer according to your comment.